# Solving Second order Differential Equation involving square of first derivative.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following second-order differential equation

$a \ddot a + (\gamma) \dot a ^2 - (\alpha) a^2 + (\gamma K ) = 0$

Here $a$ is a function of $t$ i.e. $a(t)$ and  $\gamma$, $\alpha$, $K$ are constants such that $\alpha > 0$, $K$ can be anything (positive, zero or negative) and $\gamma = (3k+1)/2$ where $k \ge 0$.

[Note:  When $K = 0$, I got the answer. But I want the answer for a general $K$.

When $K =0$, by substituting $\dot{a}/a = u$, $\Rightarrow \ddot{a} /a = \dot{u} + u^2$, the solution is

$a(t) = C_2   \cosh\left(\frac{ \sqrt{3 \alpha (1+k)}}{\sqrt2}  t + \frac{C_1}{2}\right)^{\left(\frac{2}{3(1+k)}\right)}$

(Note that $K$ and $k$ are different.)]

Comment: Why are there brackets around the constants? Is this some kind of special notation? Please share your background and attempts to solve the ODE.

Comment: Additionally, why dont you refer to the "$\ddot a$" as "second derivative"? I have never heard the terminology "cross term" before.

Comment: @maxmilgram I have given brackets around the constants to distinguish between constants and variables clearly. There is no other meaning to it. $\ddot a$ is a second derivative but it is again multiplied by a.

Comment: What this ODE is supposed to model? Are you looking for its general solution, or a solution satisfying a particular set of initial conditions?

Comment: @Gonçalo  I am looking for a general solution. There are no set of initial conditions.

Comment: @apk What is $k$ in the addendum to your OP? Is it an integer?

Comment: @CW279 k is anything greater than or equal to zero

Comment: @apk OK, I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since your equation is autonomous, we can reduce it to a first-order equation by making the substitution

$$
\begin{align}
a'(t)&=u(a)\\
a''(t)&=u(a)\,u'(a)
\end{align}
$$

In doing so, we find

$$
\begin{align}
auu'+\gamma u^2-\alpha a^2+\gamma K&=0\\
uu'+\frac{\gamma}{a}u^2&=\left(\alpha a-\frac{\gamma K}{a}\right)
\end{align}
$$

which is Bernoulli's equation, and suggests a second transformation

$$
\begin{align}
w(a)&=u(a)^2\\
w'(a)&=2u(a)\,u'(a)
\end{align}
$$

We thereby obtain

$$
w'+\frac{2\gamma}{a}\,w
=\left(2\alpha a-\frac{2\gamma K}{a}\right)
$$

This is a linear first-order equation with the integrating factor

$$
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\int^a da'\frac{2\gamma}{a'}\right)
&=\exp(2\gamma\ln{a})\\
&=a^{2\gamma}
\end{align}
$$

Hence

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{da}\left(wa^{2\gamma}\right)
&=\left(2\alpha a^{2\gamma+1}-2\gamma Ka^{2\gamma-1}\right)\\
wa^{2\gamma}
&=\frac{\alpha a^{2\gamma+2}}{\gamma+1}-Ka^{2\gamma}+c_1\\
w&=\frac{\alpha a^2}{\gamma+1}-K+c_1a^{-2\gamma}
\end{align}
$$

Now we have to invert all our transforms. We find

$$
\begin{align}
a'^2
&=\frac{\alpha a^2}{\gamma+1}-K+c_1a^{-2\gamma}\\
\pm dt
&=\frac{da}{\sqrt{\frac{\alpha a^2}{\gamma+1}-K+c_1a^{-2\gamma}}}\\
&=\frac{da}{\sqrt{\frac{2\alpha a^2}{3k+3}-K+c_1a^{-(3k+1)}}}
\end{align}
$$

I'm not inclined to believe the integral on the RHS can be done for arbitrary $k$. Suppose we're interested in the case $k=1/3$. Choose $\alpha=2$ for simplicity. Then

$$
\begin{align}
t-t_0
&=\pm\int \frac{da}{\sqrt{a^2-K+\frac{c_1}{a^2}}}
\end{align}
$$

According to WolframAlpha, this integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions as

$$
t-t_0
=\mp\frac12\,\mbox{sgn}(a)\,\mbox{arctanh}\!\left(
\frac{K-2a^2}{2\sqrt{c_1-Ka^2+a^4}}
\right)
$$

assuming $a(t),K,c_1$ are all real.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But $\gamma$ can not be -1/2. I have edited the question.

Comment: In the expression of $\omega$, you have $\frac{-K}{\gamma}$. That term should be -K, right?

Comment: @apk Indeed it should! Thanks- I've corrected my answer.

Comment: In the answer above, you say, "I am not inclined to believe the integral above can be done for arbitrary k. If I adjusted some constants in my problem, then what I get is $\int  \frac{da}{\sqrt{\frac{8 \pi G \Lambda}{3}a^2 - K +c_{1} a^{-(3k+1)}}}$ where k $\ge$ 0, G$>$ 0, $\Lambda$ $>$ 0 and K can be zero, positive or negative as earlier. Can this integral be solved for an arbitrary k?

Comment: @apk Playing around on Maple suggests there are solutions only for the cases $k=0$ and $k=1/3$. Maple is unable to evaluate that integral for arbitrary $k$.